# Class-in-class object constructor/initialization fails

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I'm pretty new to C++ terminology so hopefully my title is not too off. But I'm 100% sure that someone will tell me ;)

I have this piece of code:

```
struct B {
  struct A {
    A() : a(0) { }
    A(int a) { this->a = a; }
    int a;
  }
    a0,    // OK
    a1(1); // NOT OK!

  B() : b(0) { }
  B(int b) { this->b = b; }
  int b;
}
  b0,    // OK
  b1(1); // OK
```

But gcc fails to compile and generates this output:

```
8:8: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
8:8: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
2:3: error: new types may not be defined in a return type
2:3: note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of ‘B::A’)
```

If I remove 'a1(1)' object or change it to 'a1' then it compiles without problems. But then I can't make use of 'A(int a)' constructor. The similar? object 'b1' has no problems with its contructor. What's the explanation for this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to initialize a member variable within the class/struct defintion (exception: `static const` integral (e.g. `int`, `short`, `bool`) members)

In the case of `b0` and `b1`, you are declaring (and initializing) two global variables, not member variables

Comment: except static const **integral** types (pre-C++11)

Comment: Attila and co - thx :) @juanchopanza - so you say this code is actually valid in C++11? I actually did compile with -std=c++0x :S

Comment: @Jens : What version of GCC are you using? [This page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) notes that support only exists in GCC 4.7+.

Comment: @JensSchwarzer valid c++11, but gcc only supports it since 4.7 as ildjarn said.

Comment: @juanchopanza just installed version 4.7.0 and tried it out - but the same error is reported (with -std=c++11). Any clue? Thx :)

Comment: @juanchopanza After reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) I've changed from `a1(1)` to `a1{1}` and then it compiled with gcc 4.7.0 :)

Answer (score 3):

You are mismatching objects and instances.
You cannot have a pre-constructed object (an instance of A) in the definition of class B, unless it is static const, but then you wouldn't still be able to initialize it in the class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`a0` and `a1` are members of the outer struct, and just like normal attributes, you cannot initalize them inline. You'll need to initialize `a0` and `a1` in your `B` constructor initalizer lists.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for the correct syntax..,

```
struct B {
    struct A {
        int a;

        A()      : a(0) { }
        A(int a) : a(a) { }
    } a0, a1;

    int b;

    B()      : a0(), a1(1), b(0) { }
    B(int b) : a0(), a1(1), b(b) { }
} b0, b1(1);
```

Comment: Great thanks - but when exactly is the constructor then called? I mean if a0/a1 isn't initialized in B's constructor is the constructors in A not used then?

Comment: @Jens : `a0` and `a1` _are_ initialized in `B`'s constructors -- `B() : a0(), a1(1), b(0) { }` and `B(int b) : a0(), a1(1), b(b) { }`. Perhaps you're not familiar with the syntax for [constructor initialization lists](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html#faq-10.6)?

Comment: I meant if I reduced B's constructor to only initialize 'b' and not 'a0' and 'a1' then we would still have 'a0' and 'a1' as instances right? But would their constructor have been called?

Comment: @Jens : Yes, `A` has a non-trivial default constructor, so that will be called automatically if you omit `a0` or `a1` from `B`'s constructor initialization list. If `A` were instead a POD-type, it would remain altogether uninitiailized.